# How to Change the Value of an element in a df Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Overbuff_scraped_22-04-2019.csv',encoding='latin')
df.to_csv('Overbuff_scraped_22-04-2019.csv',encoding='utf-8')
df2 = df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'],axis=1)
df2.rename(columns={'Pick_rate':'PickRate','Win_rate':'WinRate','Tie_Rate':'TieRate','On_fire':'OnFire'},inplace=True)
df2.head()
```

I would like to change the name of df2['Hero']=='LÃºcio' to 'Lucio'. I do not know how to do this.

I have tried:

```
df2.rename(df2['Hero']=='LÃºcio', 'Lucio')
```

but this does not work.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the name , it is value , so we do

```
df2.loc[df2['Hero']=='LÃºcio','Hero'] = 'Lucio'
```